# OpenVpn Run as a service not working

Tags: openvpn

I've setup OpenVpn (2.4.7) on a server(Windows server 2012) with automatically start service,OpenVpn interactive service:AUTOMATIC
Client connection works, but If system is restarted on server (windows update,etc) and let it into user login window the client can't connect until a login is done and run Connect on OpenVpn GUI(on server). how to fix that?in case on server restart all clients connections will be down until someone log to server and run OpenVpn GUI Connect

thanks

Comment: Is the OpenVPN _service_ running as a real Windows service, set to automatic?

Comment: hi.yes service is set to  automatic start.thanks

Comment: Which user is the owner of the service?

Comment: service is installed on admin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved creating a windows task for  **openvpn-gui.exe** arguments:  **--connect "config.ovpn"**
on task check 'user logged in or not' trigger: at startup